# How to discretize space polygon with hole?

Tags: regions, mesh, opencascade

When we using `Polygon[{p1, p2, ..., pn} -> {q1, q2, ..., qn}]` to draw a space polygon with hole, it seems that `DiscretizeGraphics` does not work for such region. Is there any other way to do such discretize?

```
polys = PolyhedronData["TruncatedIcosahedron", "Polygons"] /. 
   Polygon[pts_] :> 
    Polygon[N@pts -> Threaded[.2 Mean[N@pts]] + .8 N@pts];
c60 = Graphics3D[polys, Boxed -> False]
```

[image]

```
{DiscretizeGraphics[c60], DiscretizeGraphics[polys[[1]]]}
```

> `{EmptyRegion[3], EmptyRegion[2]}`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems be a bug of `DiscretizeGraphics`. Here we use `OpenCascadeLink`.

```
Needs["OpenCascadeLink`"];
polys = PolyhedronData["TruncatedIcosahedron", "Polygons"] /. 
   Polygon[pts_] :> 
    OpenCascadeShapeDifference @@ 
     OpenCascadeShape /@ {Polygon[pts], 
       Polygon[Threaded[.2 Mean[pts]] + .8 pts]};
mesh = OpenCascadeShapeSurfaceMeshToBoundaryMesh[
  OpenCascadeShapeUnion[polys]]
mesh // MeshRegion
mesh["Wireframe"]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here an alternative solution for Mathematica version <13:

```
polyStrip[polygon_] := 
Block[
{pts = MeshPrimitives[polygon, 0] /. Point -> Identity, ptsN,ptsC, np}, 
np = Length[pts]; ptsC = Mean[pts]; 
ptsN = Table[ptsC + .8 (pi - ptsC), {pi, pts}];
MeshRegion[
Join[pts,ptsN], {Join[Table[Polygon[{i, i + 1, i + 1 + np, i + np}], {i, 1,np - 1}], {Polygon[{np, 1, np + 1, 2 np}]}] }]
]

Show@Map[polyStrip,polys]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
ClearAll[f]
f[x_] := BlockMap[
  N @ Join[Reverse @ #, ScalingTransform[4/5 {1, 1, 1}, Mean @ x] /@ #] &, 
  Append[First @ x] @ x, 2, 1]

Apply[RegionUnion] @ 
 ReplaceAll[Polygon -> Polygon @* f] @
  PolyhedronData["TruncatedIcosahedron", "Polygons"]
```

[image]